# Server doesn't respond to an xmlHTTP request using the get method

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a project with arduino in which I send different requests to the server (the arduino board) with the method XMLHttprequest and Get from a webpage. Except one of the request the others are used only for sending orders to the server, so I don't expect for an XML response. The other one is a request sent in intervals of 5 seconds for getting different values from the server.

The problem arrives with this last one. Actually the webpage sends the request (because I see it on the browser console and the arduino serial monitor) every 5 seconds, but it doesn't get anything, just the headers of the answer confirming the response but nothing about the XML file. Surprisingly, when I write a normal request using the get method in the browser I get instantly the XML file with the values, and It happens all the time I do that.

I'm going to write the javascript code I'm using on the webpage

```
setInterval(function tiempo()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                if (this.responseXML != null) {
//                  extract XML data from XML file (containing switch states and analog value)
                    document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("input3").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("input4").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[3].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("input5").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("input6").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("input7").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('dato')[6].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "URL" + Math.random(), true);
    request.send(null);
}
, 5000);
```

On the other hand, if I only write in the browser `URL`, I get the XML without any problem.

One las thing I have to say is that right now I'm using a webpage stored in my computer but before I was using a webpage stored in the arduino (on an SD card) and loaded also through the internet from arduino. The same code in that case worked perfectly. The reason because I changed It is because arduino ethernet is not too fast and It took so much time. With the webpage stored in my computer It goes faster because It only needs to send the orders.

Thanks!!

Comment: No!! I have used that to codify the post. The url is de address of the server. It is well written because the webpage sends the requests and it obtains a response, but without the XML file.

Comment: If the request is sent, the problem is not with your JS code. Figure out what is different between the "normal" request the browser makes, and the XHR your JS makes. The server responds to those differently.

Comment: I've been taking a look at the request and the only difference is that the xml request sends "null" in a part called "Origin". Could it be that?

Comment: I don't think so... The URLs are exactly the same ? What about that random...

Comment: The random is only for avoiding the cache. I tried without it and nothing happened. Arduino looks for a word in the request for sending the response, and in both cases it does it, but in the xml request it only sends the headers of the response not the content of the xml file. That's the problem.

Comment: I figured out something more. In the serial monitor of arduino there's a difference between the both requests. The normal request (without XMLhttp) sends also this "Host: ip of the client" and it appears on the monitor. The other one doesn't send that.

Comment: Fake alarm. The serial monitor doesn't show the host because of the length of the math random. I supposed it sends that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the problem. It is the browser. For any reason only Internet Explorer works correctly with the webpage. Neither firefox nor other web browsers got the xml file. I don't know the reason but I would like  to find it.

If someone knows something about I would be glad of trying to resolve the problem.

Thanks!!